# TableViewCell with different background

Tags: objective-c, ios8, tableview

How can I make different background on every TableView cell?
I tried to use this code, but it didn't work, the result just give blue color for each cell.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleIndentifier];

for(i=0; i <= rowCount; i++){
    if (indexPath.row == i){
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:i/rowCount green:.8 blue:1 alpha:1]];
    }
    continue;
}
```

Comment: If you are using any kind of default cells, try this: [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:i/rowCount green:.8 blue:1 alpha:1]];

Comment: @OnikIV it doesn't work. Just show blue background on each cell.

Comment: Then it must be either:

1) You are selecting the color wrong so try: [UIColor colorWithRed:(i/rowCount)/255.f green:.8/255.f blue:1/255.f alpha:1]];

2) You have another view on top of contentView with that color.

Comment: @OnikIV Then It shows black color on each cell. I just have one tableView.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `setBackgroundColor` on a UITableViewCell, you use the inherited backgroundColor property of the UIView class. But depending on the UITableViewStyle you need to change the `backgroundView` of the UITableViewCell, if that is not nil, as, if set, the backgroundView overlays the UITableViewCell.

See the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html)! There is an extra paragraph in the class description about how to set the background.

Answer (score 0):

TableViewCells contain a ContentView that holds all your views. So you must change the cell.contentView background color property instead of the actual cell one.

Comment: You mean change into this: [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:i/rowCount green:.8 blue:1 alpha:1]]; ?

Comment: I also change into this cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:i/rowCount green:.8 blue:1 alpha:1]; but the result is same, show blue background color on each cell.